# Cannot validate XML with import tag generically in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

i want to validate the XML with XSD schema that contains the `<import>` tag which refers to another schema. But dont want to add those manually in SchemaSet. First i am not able to validate because SchemaSet is unable to find the import namespaces which i had to add manually. I have the below code:

```
 XmlSchemaSet tempSchemaDocs = new XmlSchemaSet
            {
                XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver()
            };
            tempSchemaDocs.Add(MainXsdDoc);
            
            tempSchemaDocs.Add("http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon", path + "\\secondXsdDoc.xsd"); // this one is imported in MainXsdDoc but its unable to do it so i have to add manually .. which i also dont want to.
            tempSchemaDocs.Add("http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IsoTypes", path + "\\thirdXsdDoc.xsd");  // this one is imported in secondXsdDoc but its unable to do it so i have to add manually .. which ia also dont want to.
            tempSchemaDocs.Add("urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:fiscalis:common:v1", path + "\\FourthXsdDoc.xsd");
            
            tempSchemaDocs.Compile();

// the path for XSDs is S3 but i only have the mainXSD on S3 not the others . the path in code is for trying to resolve them manually which i need to overcome.
```

it still does not get all the validation since it says its missing declarations. But is there any way where i dont have to add the import schemas manually

the main schema that is importing the second one is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment" xmlns:common="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" targetNamespace="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0" xml:lang="en">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" schemaLocation="IntervatInputCommon_v0_9.xsd"/>
    
    <!-- Root Element -->
    <xs:element name="VATConsignment">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Envoi regroupé de déclarations TVA périodiques, déposé par un mandataire</xs:documentation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Gegroepeerde verzending van periodische btw aangiften, voorgelegd door een gevolmachtigde</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Representative" type="common:Representative_Type" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Mandataire</xs:documentation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Gevolmachtigde</xs:documentation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="de">Bevollmächtigter</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="RepresentativeReference" type="common:RepresentativeReference_Type" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Référence attribuée à l'envoi par le mandataire</xs:documentation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Toegekende referentie aan de zending door de gevolmachtigde</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="VATDeclaration" type="VATDeclaration_Type" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Déclaration périodique à la TVA, pour un déclarant et une période</xs:documentation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Periodieke aangifte, voor een belastingplichtige en een periode</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="VATDeclarationsNbr" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Nombre de déclarations TVA périodiques dans l'envoi</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Aantal periodieke aangiften in de zending</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <!-- definition of complex types -->
    <xs:complexType name="VATDeclaration_Type">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Déclaration TVA périodique, pour un déclarant et une période</xs:documentation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Periodieke aangifte, voor een aangever en een periode</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ReplacedVATDeclaration" type="common:IntervatDeclarationReference_Type" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Identifiant/Référence Intervat d'une déclaraton TVA périodique précédente qui est remplacée par cette déclaration (référence donnée dans l'accusé de réception de la déclaration originale)</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Identificatie/Referentie Intervat van een vorige aangifte welke wordt vervangen door deze aangifte(referentie terug te vinden in de ontvangstbevestiging van de originele aangifte)</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Declarant" type="common:Declarant_Type">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Déclarant (assujetti belge)</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Aangever (Belgische belastingplichtige)</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Period" type="VATPeriod_Type">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Période couverte par la déclaration TVA périodique (un mois ou un trimestre d'une année)</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Deduction" type="common:VATDeduction_Type" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr"> % de déduction de TVA par année</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl"> % recht op aftrek voor een welbepaald jaar</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Data" type="Data_Type">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montants déclarés. Tous les montants sont exprimés en EUR à l'eurocent près. (grille 71 ou 72 obligatoire)</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Aangegeven bedragen. Alle bedragen zijn in Euro uitgedrukt. </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ClientListingNihil" type="common:YesNo_Type">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Concerne uniquement la dernière déclaration civile ou celle relative à la cessation d'activité: pas de clients à reprendre sur le listing des clients.</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Betreft uitsluitend de laatste aangifte van het kalenderjaar of de aangifte met betrekking tot de stopzetting van activiteit: geen klanten op te nemen in de klantenlisting.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Ask">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Demandes liées à la déclaration (remboursement et formulaires de paiement)</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Aanvragen verbonden aan de aangifte (terugbetaling en betaalformulieren) </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Restitution" type="common:YesNo_Type" use="required">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Demande de restitution</xs:documentation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Aanvraag om terugbetaling</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:attribute>
                    <xs:attribute name="Payment" type="common:YesNo_Type" use="required">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Demande de formulaires de paiement</xs:documentation>
                            <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Aanvraag van betaalformulieren</xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="FileAttachment" type="common:FileAttachment_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Informations concernant une annexe</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Informatie betreffende een bijlage</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="de">Informationen zu einer Anlage</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Comment" type="common:Comment_Type" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Commentaire libre</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Vrije commentaar</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="de">Freier Kommentar</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Justification" type="common:Justification_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Information contenant une justification</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">a faire</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="de">a faire</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Numéro de séquence de la déclaration TVA périodique dans l'envoi</xs:documentation>
                <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Volgnummer van de aangifte in de zending</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="DeclarantReference" type="common:DeclarantReference_Type">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Référence attribuée à cette déclaration TVA périodique par le déclarant ou mandataire</xs:documentation>
                <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Toegekende referentie aan de aangifte door de aangever of de mandataris</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="VATPeriod_Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="Month" type="common:Month_Type">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Mois de la période</xs:documentation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Maand van de periode</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Quarter" type="common:Quarter_Type">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Trimestre de la periode</xs:documentation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Kwartaal van de periode</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Year" type="common:Year_Type">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Année de la période (format YYYY)</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Jaar van de periode (formaat YYYY)</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Data_Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Amount" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Montant en EUR</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="common:PositiveAmount_Type">
                            <xs:attribute name="GridNumber" type="GridNumberCode" use="required">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Numéro de la case</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:attribute>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="GridNumberCode">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:enumeration value="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 00: opérations soumises à un régime particulier</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 00: handelingen onderworpen aan een bijzondere regeling</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 01: opérations pour lesquelles la T.V.A. est due par le déclarant au taux de 6%</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 01: Handelingen waarvoor de btw verschuldigd is door de aangever aan het tarief van 6%</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="2">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 02: opérations pour lesquelles la T.V.A. est due par le déclarant au taux de 12%</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 02: Handelingen waarvoor de btw verschuldigd is door de aangever aan het tarief van 12%.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="3">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 03: opérations pour lesquelles la T.V.A. est due par le déclarant au taux de 21%</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 03: handelingen waarvoor de btw verschuldigd is door de aangever aan het tarief van 21%.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="44">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 44: services pour lesquels la T.V.A. étrangère est due par le cocontractant</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 44: diensten waarvoor de buitenlandse btw verschuldigd is door de medecontractant</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="45">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 45: opérations pour lesquelles la T.V.A. est due par le cocontractant</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 45: handelingen waarvoor de btw verschuldigd is door de medecontractant</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="46">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 46: livraisons intracommunautaires exemptées effectuées en Belgique et ventes ABC</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 46: vrijgestelde intracommunautaire leveringen in België en ABC-verkopen</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="47">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 47: autres opérations exemptées et autres opérations effectuées à l'étranger</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 47: andere vrijgestelde handelingen en andere handelingen verricht in het buitenland</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="48">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 48: Montant des notes de crédit délivrées et des corrections négatives relatif aux opérations inscrites en grilles 44 et 46</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 48: bedrag van de uitgereikte creditnota's en de negatieve verbeteringen met betrekking tot de handelingen ingeschreven in roosters 44 en 46</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="49">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 49: Montant des notes de crédit délivrées et des corrections négatives relatif aux autres opérations du cadre II</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 49: bedrag van de uitgereikte creditnota's en de negatieve verbeteringen met betrekking tot andere handelingen van kader II</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="54">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 54: T.V.A. relative aux opérations déclarées en grilles 01, 02 et 03</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 54: btw op handelingen aangegeven in de roosters 01, 02 et 03</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="55">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 55: T.V.A. relative aux opérations déclarées en grilles 86 et 88</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 55: btw op handelingen aangegeven in roosters 86 en 88</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="56">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 56: T.V.A. relative aux opérations déclarées en grille 87, à l'exception des importations avec report de perception</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 56: btw op handelingen aangegeven in rooster 87, met uitzondering van invoeren met verlegging van heffing</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="57">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 57: T.V.A. relative aux importations avec report de perception</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 57: btw op invoeren met verlegging van heffing</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="59">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 59: T.V.A. déductible</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 59: Aftrekbare btw</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="61">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 61: diverses régularisations T.V.A. en faveur de l'Etat</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 61: diverse btw-regularisaties in het voordeel van de Staat</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="62">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 62: diverses régularisations T.V.A. en faveur du déclarant</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 62: diverse btw-regularisaties in het voordeel van de aangever</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="63">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 63: T.V.A. à reverser mentionnée sur les notes de crédit reçues</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 63: terug te storten btw vermeld op ontvangen creditnota's</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="64">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 64: T.V.A. à récupérer mentionnée sur les notes de crédit délivrées</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 64: te recupereren btw vermeld op uitgereikte creditnota's</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="71">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 71: taxe due à l'Etat</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 71: aan de Staat verschuldigde belasting</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="72">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 72: sommes dues par l'Etat</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 72: sommen verschuldigd door de Staat</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="81">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 81: Montant des opérations à l'entrée compte tenu des notes de crédit reçues et autres corrections : marchandises, matières premières et matières auxiliaires</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 81: bedrag van de inkomende handelingen rekening houdend met de ontvangen creditnota's en andere verbeteringen: handelsgoederen, grond- en hulpstoffen </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="82">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 82: Montant des opérations à l'entrée compte tenu des notes de crédit reçues et autres corrections :services et biens divers</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 82: bedrag van de inkomende handelingen rekening houdend met de ontvangen creditnota's en andere verbeteringen: diensten en diverse goederen </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="83">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 83: Montant des opérations à l'entrée compte tenu des notes de crédit reçues et autres corrections : biens d'investissement</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 83: bedrag van de inkomende handelingen rekening houdend met de ontvangen creditnota's en andere verbeteringen: bedrijfsmiddelen</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="84">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 84: Montant des notes de crédit reçues et des corrections négatives relatif aux opérations inscrites en grilles 86 et 88</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 84: bedrag van de ontvangen creditnota's en de negatieve verbeteringen met betrekking tot de handelingen ingeschreven in roosters 86 en 88</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="85">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 85: Montant des notes de crédit reçues et des corrections négatives : relatif aux autres opérations du cadre III</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 85: bedrag van de ontvangen creditnota's en de negatieve verbeteringen met betrekking tot de andere handelingen van kader III</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="86">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 86: acquisitions intracommunautaires effectuées en Belgique et vente ABC</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 86: intracommunautaire verwervingen verricht in België en ABC-verkopen</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="87">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 87: autres opérations à l'entrée pour lesquelles la T.V.A. est due par le déclarant</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 87: andere inkomende handelingen waarvoor de btw verschuldigd is
door de aangever</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="88">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Montant déclaré en grille 88: services intracommunautaires avec report de perception</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Bedrag aangegeven in rooster 88: intracommunautaire diensten met verlegging van heffing</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="91">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Concerne uniquement la déclaration mensuelle de décembre: Montant déclaré en grille 91: T.V.A. réellement due pour la période du 1er au 20 décembre</xs:documentation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="nl">Betreft uitsluitend de maandaangifte van december: bedrag aangegeven in rooster 91: werkelijk verschuldigde btw voor de periode van 1 tot 20 december </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

and my xml to validate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>     
 <ns2:VATConsignment xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" xmlns:ns2="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/VATConsignment" VATDeclarationsNbr="1">
  <ns2:Representative>
   <RepresentativeID identificationType="" issuedBy=""></RepresentativeID>
   <Name></Name>
   <Street></Street>
   <PostCode></PostCode>
   <City></City>
   <CountryCode></CountryCode>
   <EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
   <Phone></Phone>
  </ns2:Representative>
  <ns2:VatDeclaration DeclarantReference="" ClientsNbr="1" SequenceNumber="1">
   <ns2:Declarant>
    <VATNumber></VATNumber>
    <Name></Name>
    <Street> </Street>
    <PostCode></PostCode>
    <City></City>
    <CountryCode></CountryCode>
    <EmailAddress></EmailAddress>
    <Phone></Phone>
   </ns2:Declarant>
   <ns2:Period>
    <ns2:Month></ns2:Month>
    <ns2:Quarter></ns2:Quarter>
    <ns2:Year></ns2:Year>
   </ns2:Period>
   <ns2:Deduction></ns2:Deduction>
   <ns2:Data>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="0">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="1">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="2">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="3">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="44">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="45">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="46">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="47">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="48">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="49">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="54">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="55">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="56">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="57">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="59">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="61">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="62">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="63">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="64">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="65">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="66">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="71">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="72">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="81">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="82">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="83">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="84">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="85">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="86">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="87">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="88">0</ns2:Amount>
   <ns2:Amount GridNumber="91">0</ns2:Amount>
   </ns2:Data> 
   <ns2:Comment></ns2:Comment>
  </ns2:VatDeclaration>
 </ns2:VATConsignment>
```

now what happens is that it gives error about soe types that are not declared in the Xsd above. becasue that type is present in the `import` namespace which is a separate schema. I dont want that second schema to be added manually because the first one is on S3 and we cant have all of them to be on S3. Is there any way C# should resolve these imports rather then adding them manually in schema set ?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? It's impossible to guess why the imports are not loaded without seeing the schema that imports them.

Comment: @CharlesMager updated my question with that particular import tag ..

Comment: That's still not a [mcve]. What is `MainXsdDoc`? An `XmlSchema`? If so, where is it loaded and how? Are the two files in the same directory? I want to be able to take your code and your XML schemas and be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: i updated the question with the xsd and xmls i have .. reagrding the source i have my mainXsd on S3 and others are imported in it but i dont have them on S3 and i dont want them to be path i mentioned in the code is just for testing it manually i cant add them to some physical location.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect it to work, then. If your schema imports something from a relative path and the file isn't there, then it's not going to load it. Where are you proposing it find this file?

Comment: should'nt the schemaSet resolve this import ` <xs:import namespace="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" schemaLocation="secondxsd.xsd"/>` itself ? ... but it does'nt thats y i had to add those manually ... but its not resolved on its on i will have to put these all on S3 which i dont wan to.

Comment: It will resolve that import, using the uri of the importing schema and the relative uri in `schemaLocation`. So if the uri is `http://example.com/schemas/mainSchema.xsd`, it will try `http://example.com/schemas/secondxsd.xsd` and presumably fail because it's not there. I'm not sure how else you think it's going to resolve it? All it has to go on is the file name.

Comment: yup so its not able to find it on the URI .. the only option i have is to get those manually and add them on S3 as well.